# Как спозиционировать блок

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, position

Есть адаптивная структура в которой 2 блока: в первом контент может быть любой высоты, а во втором есть картинка и блок с классом `absolute`, который нужно спозиционировать в правом нижнем углу всего контейнера независимо от высоты первого блока.
Набросал [фидл](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/12511/)

```css
@import "//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css";
@import "//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css";

body {
  margin: 10px;
}
.relative {
  position: relative;
}
.absolute {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
      <p>this is sparta</p>
      <p>this is sparta</p>
      <p>this is sparta</p>
      <p>this is sparta</p>
      <p>this is sparta</p>
      <p>this is sparta</p>
      <p>this is sparta</p>
      <p>this is sparta</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 relative">
      <img class="profile-pic" src="http://cdn.cutestpaw.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/l-Wittle-puppy-yawning.jpg" width="100" height="100" />
      <p class="absolute">this is sparta</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Как это можно сделать, причем, чтобы на малых разрешениях блоки съезжали 1 под один и пустота между картинкой и блоком исчезала?

Answer (score 1):

Вообщем-то, единственно правильный вариант я вижу такой: у колоночного блока назначить статическое позиционирование, а у контейнера соответственно относительное - вот так [ссылка на фидл](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/12519/)

```css
/* Latest compiled and minified CSS included as External Resource*/

/* Optional theme */

@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');
 body {
  margin: 10px;
}
.container {
  position: relative;
}
.relative {
  position: static;
}
.absolute {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5px;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .absolute {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -25px;
    left: 15px;
    margin: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
      <p>this is sparta</p>
      <p>this is sparta</p>
      <p>this is sparta</p>
      <p>this is sparta</p>
      <p>this is sparta</p>
      <p>this is sparta</p>
      <p>this is sparta</p>
      <p>this is sparta</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 relative">
      <img class="profile-pic" src="http://cdn.cutestpaw.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/l-Wittle-puppy-yawning.jpg" width="100" height="100" />
      <p class="absolute">this is sparta</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
.container {
  position:relative;
}
.relative {
  position:static;
}
```

Спасибо за помощь - вопрос решен!

Comment: это не решение !

Comment: @LenovoID в смысле не решение? оно меня полностью устраивает)